# How to stop back end process when ajax call aborted in nodejs express?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am working in mean stack application.

I am using angular js for frond end, using angucomple-alt(auto complete) for searching, ajax call every enter character and aborted if previous ajax call if not complete.

If i type continues four character than first 3 ajax call aborted and fourth complete than working ok, but in back end site process not aborted(node js express).

Can any body help me, how to aborted process in back end side when ajax call aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function(req, res) {
        req.on("close", function(err) {
            console.log("request aborted...");
            res.end();
        });
}
```